# Omnisharp commands are not found

Tags: c#, omnisharp

I want to execute omnisharp command from command palette in VS Code, but I get an error that command not found. And thus no command is found:
[Restart omnisharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muus3.png)
[Select project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0x0z.png)
Atc.

Tried to update C# extension, but it not help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.